# merging datasets using get() function

Tags: r, function, get

I want to merge two data.tables using the get function to call a particular variable name but it doesn't work:

```
x = data.table("class" = c(1,2,3,4,4,5), "series" = c("a", "aaa", "cc", "a", "aaa", "a"))
y = data.table("class2" = c(1,2,3,4,5,5), "range" = c(11, 11, 4, 13, 5, 8))
var = "class"
x[y, on = .(get(var) = class2), range := i.range]
```

I get the following error:

> Error: unexpected '=' in "x[y, on = .(get(var) ="

Can anyone help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is easier with `setNames` to create a named vector where the name will be the column name from x data

```
x[y, range := i.range, on = setNames('class2', var)]
```

-output

```
x
#   class series range
#1:     1      a    11
#2:     2    aaa    11
#3:     3     cc     4
#4:     4      a    13
#5:     4    aaa    13
#6:     5      a     8
```

Comment: Thank you! The first argument of setNames has to be the variable of the second dataset (i.e. y) ?

Comment: @Margherita it should be the same order as in the solution as `x[y, on = setNames(var, 'class2')]` rerturns error because the name is one on the lhs of `=`.  It is like creating `c(class = 'class2')` and `setNames('class2',  var)`

Comment: Thank you @akrun! Another question: in the dataset y, the class '5' has to 2 different ranges, i.e. '5' and '8'. If I want to get both when I merge x and y, how can I do ? I would like to have in x two different rows for class '5', each with the different class. P.S: using the original names of the columns, not important to use the variable 'var'